# Allow only 8 selection in a Telerik radTreeListView

Tags: telerik, radtreeview

I have a radTreeListView with multiple parent nodes,which can contain multiple child nodes which can also contain multiple sub-child nodes.

I want to make sure only 8 items are selected and no more than that. Those 8 selections MUST also be under the same parent node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
private RadTreeNode GetParentNode(RadTreeNode currentNode) {
   if (currentNode.Parent!=null) {
      return GetParentNode(currentNode.Parent);
   }   
   return currentNode;
}

private void CountSelectedNodes(RadTreeNode firstNode, ref int selectedCount) {
   if (firstNode.Nodes!=null) {
      foreach(RadTreeNode node in firstNode.Nodes) {
         CountSelectedNodes(node, ref selectedCount);
      }
      if (firstNode.IsSelected) {
          selectedCount+=1;
      }
   }
}

private bool SelectionAllowed(RadTreeNode currentNode) {
   RadTreeNode treeNode=GetParentNode(currentNode);
   int selectedCount;
   CountSelectedNodes(treeNode, ref selectedCount);
   return selectedCount<=8;
}
```

(this code is not tested so there could be some bugs)

Call selectionAllowed() with the Node currently clicked